# Defining Google App Engine Java Backend - Not being displayed in Admin Console

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a backend instance running on GAE Java but it's not working.

I have read the docs here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html

These are the steps I have taken:

1. Created a file named backends.xml with the following content

> ```
> <backends>
>    <backend name="backend_test">
>       <class>B1</class>
>       <instances>;2</instances>
>    </backend>
> </backends>
> ```

1. uploaded app to app engine and checked console. Nothing there.
2. Used AppCfg command of `appcfg.sh backends <PATH-TO-WEB-INF> start <BACKEND-NAME>`

I get a problem with step 3 where it says

```
400 Bad Request
Starting backend: backend_test
Backend 'backend_test' has not been defined.
```

But i have defined this in the backends.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload the backend definition with `appcfg.sh backends update` as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html).

Comment: That worked! thanks! I must learn to read the docs properly next time.